# Why this code does not generate an ambigous call error?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have written a **MyComplex** class and overloaded the plus (+) operator as:

```
class MyComplex
{
public:
        operator int() { return realPart; }
        MyComplex(int r, int i=0)
        {
                realPart = r;
                imaginaryPart = i;
        }

    int operator +(int i) { return imaginaryPart+i; }
private:
        int realPart, imaginaryPart;
};

int main()
{
        MyComplex c(5, 4);
        cout << c+10 << "\n"; // Why is this not ambiguous?
}
```

I thought the expression **c+10** could be interpreted either as an attempt to add two integers (**c** in **c+10** would be demoted to an integer using the conversion operator **operator int()**) or as an overload operator call through the overload operator function **int operator +(int i)**. But the program compiled without any errors and produced the output as 14. How?

Comment: exact match is better

Comment: When you write `1 + 2` can be interpreted either as an attempt to add two integers, or as an attempt to convert them both to `double` and add them?

Comment: c+10 is equivalent to c+(10) ant the perfact match is  int operator +(int i).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we figure out what `c+10` means, we do a process called overload resolution, which starts by finding all the viable candidates through name lookup.

The viable candidates in this case are:

```
MyComplex::operator+(MyComplex&, int); // via c.operator+(10)
::operator+(int, int);                 // via c.operator int() + 10
```

We then look at which conversion sequence is better. For the first overload, no conversions are necessary - `c` is an Exact Match for `MyComplex` and `10` is an Exact Match for `int`. For the second overload, the second argument is an exact match but the first argument has to undergo a user-defined conversion via `MyComplex::operator int()`.

Exact Match has higher rank than Conversion, so the first overload is preferred.

---

Note that if instead your `MyComplex::operator+()` took a `long` (for example), then the call *would* be ambiguous. Each overload would have one better and one worse conversion sequence.